# Django Python - Post not saving in Database Postgresql

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I have an issue where my Django form is not posting into my Postgres database. Payload seems like all data is captured in variables. Here is my code if anyone can shine some light?

Form is posted and redirect back to form etc however data isn't passed onto the database. Have tried this as an AJAX post too but still the same, capturing variables but not passing into the database for some reason.

Views.py

```
def createResidential(request):
if request.method!="POST":
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("apps:customers.create"))
else:
    residential_firstname=request.POST.get("residential_firstname")
    residential_lasttname=request.POST.get("residential_lasttname")
    residential_contact=request.POST.get("residential_contact")
    residential_mobile=request.POST.get("residential_mobile")
    residential_email=request.POST.get("residential_email")
    residential_houseflatno=request.POST.get("residential_houseflatno")
    residential_houseflatname=request.POST.get("residential_houseflatname")
    residential_streetname=request.POST.get("residential_streetname")
    residential_city=request.POST.get("residential_city")
    residential_county=request.POST.get("residential_county")
    residential_postcode=request.POST.get("residential_postcode")        
    try:
        postResidential=ResidentialCustomer(
            residential_firstname=residential_firstname,
            residential_lasttname=residential_lasttname,
            residential_contact=residential_contact,
            residential_mobile=residential_mobile,
            residential_email=residential_email,
            residential_houseflatno=residential_houseflatno,
            residential_houseflatname=residential_houseflatname,
            residential_streetname=residential_streetname,
            residential_city=residential_city,
            residential_county=residential_county,
            residential_postcode=residential_postcode,
        )
        postResidential.save()
        messages.success(request,"Data Save Successfully")
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('apps:customers.create'))
    except:
        messages.error(request,"Error in Saving Data")
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('apps:customers.create'))
```

Models.py

```
class ResidentialCustomer(models.Model):
residential_firstname = models.TextField()
residential_lasttname = models.TextField()
residential_contact = models.IntegerField()
residential_mobile = models.IntegerField()
residential_email = models.EmailField()
residential_houseflatno = models.IntegerField()
residential_houseflatname = models.TextField()
residential_streetname = models.TextField()
residential_city = models.TextField()
residential_county = models.TextField()
residential_postcode = models.TextField()
residential_dateCreated = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
agent = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
def __str__(self):
    return f"{self.residential_firstname} {self.residential_lasttname}"
```

Form in html page

```
    <form action="{% url 'apps:createResidential' %}" method="POST" class="vertical-navs-step">{% csrf_token %}
    <div class="form-floating">
                                                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="residential_firstname" placeholder="John">
                                                                        <label for="residential_firstname">First Name</label>
                                                                    </div>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-label right ms-auto nexttab nexttab" data-nexttab="v-pills-finish-tab">
```

Same for all other fields I need to capture into the database. Appreciate the help!

Comment: Can you add also the code to your submit button?

Comment: Sorry yes, here it is: 

<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-label right ms-auto nexttab nexttab" data-nexttab="v-pills-finish-tab">

Comment: Please put the code in the question, not in the comments

Comment: What does the Postgres log show when you save?

Comment: How can I check this?

Comment: I suspect that you are getting an error when you hit postResidential.save().  I would pull out your try/except block (for debugging) and then try again.

Comment: Hi Chris, do you have an example I could do try based on the above code? 

Or a different way to do this post?

Comment: Seconded, remove the `try ... except` for debugging. I'm guessing that one of the data values violates the constrains on the model. A blank field and `blank = False` for example.

Comment: I'd really recommend using Django Forms rather than rolling your own! Also Class-Based views CreateView / UpdateView.

Comment: Thanks Nigel, appreciate the help mate! 

I tried going down the route of Django Forms (a lot less code!!) only thing I got stuck on was the form field tags to display on my page it just never pulled through :/